# How to finish searching for elements at watir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I should save all reviews from page https://www.walmart.com/ip/Ematic-9-Dual-Screen-Portable-DVD-Player-with-Dual-DVD-Players-ED929D/28806789. For it I use Watir because it is dynamic page and I need to click button to update results. I check if button present and then scrape reviews.But when all reviews saved on last page, it don`t finish process and search for elements and after 30 seconds I have error.

Error:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException (timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Div: located: false; {:css=>".review-body-text", :index=>10, :tag_name=>:div}> to be located; Maybe look in an iframe?):
```

My code:

```
while  browser.element(:text => "Next Page").present?
      browser.elements(css:'.review-body-text').each do |comment|
        review= Review.new
        review.text=comment.text
        product.reviews<<review
        review.save
      end
        browser.button(:text => "Next Page").click
    end while  browser.element(:text => "Next Page").present?
    browser.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the next page of reviews is done asynchronously. This can result in attempting to read the reviews while they are in the process of being changed. After clicking the paging button, you need to wait for the list of reviews to finish loading.

There are likely a number of ways to detect this. The following example waits for the paging control to be updated to the new page number.

```
paginator_list = browser.ul(class: 'paginator-list')
last_page = paginator_list.button(aria_label: true, index: -1).text.to_i
1.upto(last_page) do |i|
  browser.divs(class: 'review-body-text').each do |comment|
    review= Review.new
    review.text=comment.text
    product.reviews<<review
    review.save
  end

  unless i == last_page
    browser.button(text: 'Next Page').click
    browser.wait_until do
      current = paginator_list.button(class: 'active').text.to_i
      current == i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the 'Next Page' text is not in the button, it's in the span, So write the code

```
while b.span(:text => "Next Page").present?
  b.elements(css: '.review-body-text').each do |comment|
    p comment
  end
  b.span(text: "Next Page").click
end
```

It would work for you.

Comment: No,it doesn`t work. Element <span class="visuallyhidden">...</span> is not clickable at point (593, 588).

Comment: I can click on button by code: browser.button(:text => "Next Page").click.Question was about not stopping of searching at last page.It search when all reviews are scraped and then I have error.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_all_reviews
  loop do
    # Call method to get reviews on page     
    break unless b.span(:text => "Next Page").present?
    b.span(text: "Next Page").click
  end
end
```

I think that Rubys loop do break is a better fit for this kind of operation.

I would also suggest that you assign variables to these elements to make the code easier to read like this:

```
def get_all_reviews
  loop do
    # Call method to get reviews on page     
    break unless next_page.present?
    next_page.click
  end
end
```